# Two filters on a ListObject Table

Tags: excel, vba

Is it possible to filter on multiple fields in a single table all at the same time?

I have the single filter, but am not sure how to add a second field.

```
wS.ListObjects("StructureTable").Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=wC.Range("F" & x)
```

Thanks!

Comment: A great way to figure this out is to turn on the Macro Recorder and then apply your filter. You'll have to reinsert your variables back into the generated code, but you should get the syntax for what you want. Hint: there's a `Criteria2` parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply call the `AutoFilter` method a second time and give `2` for the `Field` argument (assuming your table has 2 columns). E.g.:

```
wS.ListObjects("StructureTable").Range.AutoFilter Field:=**2**, Criteria1:=wC.Range("F" & x)
```

Full code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lst As ListObject

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
    Set lst = ws.ListObjects(1)

    'clear any existing filter
    If lst.ShowAutoFilter Then
        lst.ShowAutoFilter = False
    End If

    'set filter from range parameters
    With lst.Range
        .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=ws.Range("D1")
        .AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=ws.Range("E1")
    End With
```

End Sub

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]